# How to avoid Titanium Backup's 50 backup limit?

Tags: titanium-backup

In the Pro version I can extend backup history from 1 to 50, but it is not enough.
What should I do?

Comment: Maybe I can move some backups to another folder?Will this cause issues with Titanium?

Comment: @geffchang Im sorry but when I visit the site you provided I get:No thread specified. If you followed a valid link, please notify the administrator

Comment: Sorry, that should be: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2691743

Comment: @geffchang Thanks how did you find it? When I googled before asking here I couldn't find it

Comment: This is what I Googled: titanium backup limit